# How to remove all associated containers and an image upon Docker build

Tags: image, docker

I'm working on building a Docker image and am wondering if there's a quick way to delete a prior image built from a docker build and remove any previously rendered containers derived from the image during a Docker build.

I know I can do this separately, by removing all containers (running or stopped) associated with an image by using the ancestor filter:

`docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q --filter="ancestor=<image id>")`

and I also understand how to remove the associated container:

`docker rmi <image id>`

However, doing both steps during the next docker build would be ideal.

Comment: If you're using Docker Compose, re-running `docker-compose up` will delete and recreate the old container.  You'll still get old build images piling up, though.

Answer (score 4):

> However, doing both steps during the next docker build would be ideal.

Scripting those steps would be a simple solution, since [`docker image build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/) itself does not have those image cleanup option.

And you can add the `--no-cache` to your docker build, in order to be sure to rebuild everything.

Comment: Yes, good point. I think combining your answer with @DavidMaze comment is a good approach. I've found that unsuccessful builds do lead to left over intermediate containers so even using docker-compose doesn't guarantee that all containers will be removed. Also, using docker-compose build is probably a better approach while creating dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

**solution**

0. add the following into your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc
1. source ~/.bashrc (or the file where you put the funcs below)

**to delete the image and all associated containers**

```sh
rem_image 14a7ba8dc2c0
```

**to delete all images by patterns **

```sh
docker_clean <PATTERN>
```

for example to delete all images having no names (they're usually failed during build step)

```sh
docker images | grep none
<none>                                                <none>              e4205cbdcbd6        2 months ago        1.64GB
<none>                                                <none>              e5a21ccf4b6d        2 months ago        1.73GB
<none>                                                <none>              bd9b2ddf1a06        2 months ago        1.64GB
<none>                                                <none>              f7d08c6c4660        2 months ago        1.73GB
<none>                                                <none>              4bca4e8a7059        2 months ago        1.64GB
<none>                                                <none>              ab028586385c        2 months ago        1.73GB

docker_clean none
```

#### Code

```sh
function rem_image() {
  image_id=$1
  
  docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q --filter="ancestor=$image_id") 2>&- || echo "Found no containers for that image"
  docker rmi $image_id
  echo "Image deleted successfully"
}

function docker_clean() {
  pattern=$1

  for image_id in `docker images | grep $pattern | awk '{ print $3}'`
  do
      echo Removing... $image_id
      rem_image $image_id
  done
}
```

Comment: You make my day